# Recommended AUGraph Order when Chaining EQ's

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm working on a synthesizer that incorporates an EQ section, and would like to know if anyone has a recommendation about the order that the Audiounits are chained together.

Currently my graph looks something like this:

```
AUSampler -> Lowpass Unit -> Highpass Unit -> Parametric Unit -> Output
```

Is this the proper method of connecting them together or is there a better way?

**Or maybe a better question is: a proper desktop class multi-band eq wouldn't have each band chained together correct?**

**Maybe all the processing should be done in one render callback?**

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a kAudioUnitSubType_NBandEQ Audio Unit? You can set each bands filter type and all needed parameters. You can get a good idea of what is possible using AULab and pulling up each of the built-in Audio Units.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion! I was under the impression the NBandEQ was only available on OSX but it looks to be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

What you posted would work.

A bit redundant though. The eq au can filter out the fqs that the lp au and the hp au filter.

Moving them around would work too.
Having just the eq would work too.

The answer you probably don't want: It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Gene! Yeah sorry should have explained I'm trying to create something similar to a regular desktop eq plugin where there are multiple bands and it is presented to the user as a single eq unit. For example the Logic Pro EQ http://masteringinlogic.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Logic-Pro-EQ.png